# How to get the current Joomla username?

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to get the current Joomla username. I was able to get it by using

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
echo $user->username;
```

But now I've installed Joomla on my local server and it doesn't work anymore. The usernames are correctly stored in the database, but the code just doesn't work anymore. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean eyxactly by 'doesn't work anymore'? Do you get an error message? What does a var_dump() on $user say?

Comment: I don't get an error message, $user is just empty. var_dump($user):
object(JUser)#14 (19) { ["id"]=>  int(0) ["name"]=>  NULL ["username"]=>  NULL ["email"]=>  NULL ["password"]=>  NULL ["password_clear"]=>  string(0) "" ["usertype"]=>  NULL ["block"]=>  NULL ["sendEmail"]=>  int(0) ["gid"]=>  int(0) ["registerDate"]=>  NULL {...} ["_errorMsg"]=>  NULL ["_errors"]=>  array(0) { } }

Comment: Where was Joomla running from when it was working?

Answer (score 2):

use only : `<? echo "wellcome ". $user->username; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct way to get the username from Joomla. If that isn't working, then you have a bigger problem somewhere.